# PHPUnit giving me Too few arguments to function Tests\Unit\QuoteTest::test_count_of_quotes_equal_five()

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Too few arguments to function Tests\Unit\QuoteTest::test_count_of_quotes_equal_five(), 0 passed in E:\laragon\www\torre-task1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php on lin
e 1545 and exactly 1 expected

```
 public function execute()
{
    $quotes=[];
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
    {
        $quote=Http::get('https://api.kanye.rest/');
        $quotes[]=$quote['quote'];
    }

    return $quotes;

}
```

Testcase

```
public function test_count_of_quotes_equal_five(QuoteService $quoteService)
{
    $quotesArray =$quoteService->execute();
    $expectedCount = 5;
    $this->assertCount($expectedCount,$quotesArray);

}
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and include the relevant code as text, not an image.

Comment: please also update the question and adjust it accordingly. You may want to add some explanations to your solution. My guess is you simply did not import the `TestCase::class`.  Was removing the  injected `QuoteService::class` part of the solution?

Comment: Your issue is that Laravel or PHPUnit is not going to inject your dependency... I do not know where you thought that was going to happen...

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution to this question i will upload it incase someone need to know faced the same problem :)
[image: answer]

Comment: Do not upload images as the image will eventually go down so there will be no answer anymore...